# fzero() Matlab function for complicated functions

Tags: matlab

Having such a function:
**y=1.2*sin(x)+2*log(x+2)-5;** I am looking for zeros of that function using fzero() functon- just for testing, I indicate other methods.
I received error  and I am looking for the solution of that. fzero() is for nonlinear functions but for complex ones...? Doyou know similar method to fzero()?

Comment: the function has values in the complex plane, what are you really looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in the example has a pole, but you can treat this case by looking at it's real part, get the zero and check it to see the imaginary part is zero:

```
syms x y yr
yr= @(x) real(1.2*sin(x)+2*log(x+2)-5); 
fr=fzero(yr,0);

fr =

  6.8458


y= @(x) (1.2*sin(x)+2*log(x+2)-5); 

y(fr)

ans =

  -8.8818e-16
```